# setcap settings do not reflect in getcap

Tags: debian, ping, root-filesystem, setcap, gnuroot

```
root@localhost:~# setcap cap_net_raw+p /bin/ping
root@localhost:~# getcap /bin/ping
root@localhost:~# ls -l $(which ping)
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 34752 Nov  8  2014 /bin/ping
root@localhost:~# ping localhost
ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted
root@localhost:~#
```

Looks like for some reason my `setcap` settings do not get reflected, any idea where I'm going wrong?

Details as requested by @meuh

```
root@localhost:~# for i in /proc/fs/*/*/options ;do echo ${i}=&&cat ${i}|grep user_xattr;done

/proc/fs/ext4/mmcblk0p16/options=
user_xattr
/proc/fs/ext4/mmcblk0p25/options=
user_xattr
/proc/fs/ext4/mmcblk0p27/options=
user_xattr
/proc/fs/ext4/mmcblk0p28/options=
user_xattr

root@localhost:~# mount|grep ext4

/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system on /system type ext4 (ro,seclabel,relatime)
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata on /data type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nomblk_io_submit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic,data=ordered)
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache on /cache type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nomblk_io_submit,noauto_da_alloc,errors=panic,data=ordered)
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/persist on /persist type ext4 (rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nomblk_io_submit,nodelalloc,errors=panic,data=ordered)

root@localhost:~# df -h --output

Filesystem                                      Type  Inodes IUsed IFree IUse%  Size  Used Avail Use% File Mounted on
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata ext4    820K   35K  785K    5%   13G  1.4G   12G  12% -    /data
tmpfs                                           tmpfs   181K   486  181K    1%  928M   80K  928M   1% -    /dev
none                                            tmpfs   181K     6  181K    1%  928M   12K  928M   1% -    /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                           tmpfs   181K    22  181K    1%  928M     0  928M   0% -    /mnt

root@localhost:~# df --output -h  /bin/ping

Filesystem     Type   Inodes IUsed IFree IUse%  Size  Used Avail Use% File      Mounted on
rootfs         rootfs   820K   35K  785K    5%   13G  1.4G   12G  12% /bin/ping /
```

Comment: Perhaps your filesystem or mount does not support `user_xattr`. Look for this keyword in `/proc/fs/*/sda1/options` where `sda1` is the mounted disk.

Comment: @meuh apologies for late reply, but I was trying to figure out the `sda1` you mentioned, but failed to do so... I'm leaving output of a few commands that I think would help you, in helping me :-)

Comment: Your command `df /bin/ping` seems to show `/` is still of type `rootfs`, which may not support extended attributes (i.e. capabilities). I'm not familiar with this situation, as normally during boot this temporary rootfs is overwritten by the mount of a real `/` from a disk. Do you know how the system ended up this way?

Comment: This is a debian side loaded in an android phone via https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gnuroot.debian&hl=en. See https://github.com/corbinlc/GNURootDebian

Comment: That said do you think, there is a relationship between `ext4` and `rootfs` as both have the same `Inodes`  and usage stats...

Comment: @meuh how to figure out the relationship between `rootfs` and `ext4` mounts or is it a dumb question?

Comment: You are right, the `rootfs` type is probably just an artifact, and it is likely `ext4`. But your `getcap` should have then listed the retained capability. Sadly, this is too exotic a setup for me to help much further. You might try asking on sister site [android.stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @meuh! for looking. Do you think I should try changing the flags in all the `ext4`  `options` files from `user_xattr` to `user_xattr=1`?

Comment: hmm.. I have the same issue. The capabilities I set does not displayed when I run getcap on the executable. Found no solution or reason yet.